# Not all Math don't compile in express package

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, packages, journal

The following problem happens when I try to work with a package of a specific journal called Optics Express. You can get the relevant class in the [OSA page](https://www.osapublishing.org/submit/templates/oe/Express-LaTeX.zip).

The following text builds a proper PDF with PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[OE]{express}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\pi}{\rho}$ text text 
\end{document}
```

But the following code does not:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[OE]{express}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\pi$
\end{document}
```

Most of the times the above file seems to be compiling, but in fact it doesn't. Even if you take the OSA example from the .zip file, and try to type $\pi$ in the text, it fails.

**EDIT - Error Log:** Shows consistently the following error:

```
Font rtxmi at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I don't have the faintest idea even where to begin looking for the answer. I use MikTex 2.9.4248, and I compile PDFLaTeX all the time, so I think it has something to do with the package.

**Further Details:** The PDFLatex fails straight away, while the DVI-PS-PDF produces a PDF, but without the `$\pi$` symbol. Both `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` are not installed in my environment, nor are they available in my repository.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: The font `rtxmi` is not installed, it's not provided within the `.zip` file. It seems to be related with `newtxmath`, but I am not sure

Comment: I experience no problem compiling your code with pdflatex under MacTeX2017. Please tell us *how* you compile the tex file. Do you compile straight to pdf (with, say, pdflatex), do you try to go the -> dvi -> ps -> pdf route, or still something else? Please also tell us which TeX distribution (and which vintage) you employ. Finally, do tell us if the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages are installed on your system.

Comment: Are you really saying that using \pi within \frac{...}{...} works. i.e., the font is found, while using it directly doesn't work?

Comment: @HerbSchulz That is possible. It will be using a different size for the fraction, I assume.

Comment: @HerbSchulz To my own amazement, yes, this is what I say.

Comment: @Mico thanks, I've added the details in the OP.

Comment: @AmirSagiv - If you check inside the file `express.sty`, you'll see that the font packages`newtxtext` and `newtxmath` are required, as they provide the `rtxi*` font files. If these font packages aren't installed on your system, the `express` package cannot function properly. The solution: Install the two font packages as soon as possible. (How to perform the installation of the two missing packages depends crucially on the TeX distribution that's on your computer -- a subject about which you've disclosed no information so far.

Comment: @Mico Thanks again. In the OP I wrote I'm using MikTex 2.9.4248. Does that helps?

Comment: @AmirSagiv - Then use the MikTeX Package Manager program to install the missing packages.

Comment: @Mico the MPM didn't even find these packages in the repository...

Comment: Then something is very wrong with your current MikTeX installation! All I can suggest at this point is that you perform a full reinstallation from scratch, this time specifying that *all packages* be downloaded and installed.

Comment: @Mico The package name, as far as installation is concerned, is, I believe, `newtx` (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx), so I don't think it should be a surprise  that `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` are not present.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Thanks for this. Maybe it will help the OP locate the needed package(s).  I myself don't "do" MikTeX, so I don't know what exactly the MikTeX Package Manager utility is looking for. At any rate, I continue to think it would be a good idea for the OP to perform a full installation of the entire MikTeX distribution, with all possible packages.